# How to change the color of the year in a citation?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using a specific bibliography style and I'm currently unable to modify it the way I want it to be ;)

Reproduction steps:

1. Download http://acl2016.org/files/acl2016.zip
2. Extract `acl2016.bib`, `acl2016.sty`, and `acl2016.bst`
3. Use this minimal working example:

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article}
   \usepackage{acl2016}
   \begin{document}
   \cite{Aho:72}
   \newcite{Aho:72}
   \bibliography{acl2016}
   \bibliographystyle{acl2016}
   \end{document}
   ```

This results in

```
(Aho and Ullman, 1972) Aho and Ullman (1972)
```

I want to use another font color (e.g., blue) for the year, but only for the year. And the color should only change when I cite `\cite` or `\newcite` and not in the bibliography list. How can I achieve this with the `acl2016` style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use that specific style for submit your work somewhere, you should not change it. Otherwise, modify the .bst file is not trivial, so my suggestion is to use`biblatex` and `hyperref`.

In this way, the year is not only of another color, it is also a link to the reference. Probably the default reference style is not that you expected/need/wanted but `biblatex` is a very configurable package.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla \citep{IEEEexample:articleetal} bla bla.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For instance, as far I see the code below reproduce your exactly your MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{acl2016}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{acl2016.bib}

 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}\newunit%
  \printfield{year}\newunit%
  \printfield{title}\newunit%
  \printlist{publisher}\newunit%
  \printlist{location} \finentry} 
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\begin{document}
\citep{Aho:72}
\citet{Aho:72}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me some time to get it working though. I had to change my compile process to include biber to make it look the way it's supposed to look ;)